# How do I estimate tasks using function points?

Tags: project-planning, estimation

What are the steps to estimating using function points?

Is there a quick-reference guide of some sort out there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a conference session on Function Point Analysis a few years back.  There is a lot too it.  You can check out the [Free Function Point Training Manual](http://www.softwaremetrics.com/freemanual.htm) online, the [Fundamentals of Function Points](http://www.softwaremetrics.com/fpafund.html), or I suspect you can get a book on it at a computer store.

You might also check out the [International Function Point Users Group](http://www.ifpug.org/) and see if they have some resources or a local meeting for you.

Answer (score 4):

You really need to get some training on it. Check with IFPUG. You will unknowingly pick up some destructive bad habits if self-taught. It also helps to have an experienced FP analyst review some of your early attempts.

It's the kind of thing that appears overwhelmingly complex until you "get it" and then it's fairly quick to do. It improved my requirements analysis a lot too. I often spot contradictions and gaps when doing a count.

It isn't limited to BDUF Waterfall projects either. I spent three years using FP and Planning Poker as cross-checks on one another when contracting agile methods projects.

I was IFPUG-certified from 2002-2005 and am still using FP analysis. I've seen it misused a lot, and I think that's why it has such a bad reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at COSMIC Function points.  https://cosmic-sizing.org. COSMIC Function points are also an ISO standard for measuring software size.  They are an evolved improvement over IFPUG.

You can quickly estimate size by counting the entries, exits, reads and writes.

Compared with the IFPUG manual, learning COSMIC is much easier, the free book below is all you need, and you can read it in a day.

Recommended reading: https://cosmic-sizing.org/publications/measurement-guide/